# Editing manifest file GDI setting resuling in "application has failed to start"

Tags: c#, manifest, gdi

Once I uncomment the GDI line   true</gdiScaling>--> 
the program fails to start after compile.
This setting is being used in another application without error. Not sure how to fix this?

P.S stack overflow is not allowing me to post the manifest file, but the only lines I changed from a brand new file generated by visual studio is this:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
      **<!--<gdiScaling>true</gdiScaling>-->**
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

Comment: gdiScaling requires at least Win10 version 1703 and lives in the asmv3:windowsSettings namespace.  An example [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests).  Use Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application to find a detailed error message that tells you what is wrong with the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. In this case both were tested on the same computer, only 1 works. I'll look and see what error I got.
If i have that GDI flag enabled and an earlier windows 10 is used, would it failed to start as well or simply ignore the flag?